# Eliminate Combinations in SQL

Tags: mysql

So I have three tables (bold fields are primary keys):

---

Students = {[**Student_ID:Integer**, Name:string]}

visits  = {[**Student_ID:Integer, Lecture_ID:Integer**]}

Lectures = {[**Lecture_ID:Integer**, Title:string]}

---

and I want to get all Students, who visit the same lectures to appear next one row. So for example Daniel and Peter both visit lecture Algebra and they should be displayed like this:

```
+--------------+--------------+-------------------+
| Name         | Name         | Title             |
+--------------+--------------+-------------------+
| Daniel       | Peter        | Algebra           |
+--------------+--------------+-------------------+
```

but with my SQL-Query what happens is, that I get combinated duplicates like this:

```
+--------------+--------------+-------------------+
| Name         | Name         | Title             |
+--------------+--------------+-------------------+
| Daniel       | Peter        | Algebra           |
| Peter        | Daniel       | Algebra           |
+--------------+--------------+-------------------+
```

Here is my SQL-Statement:

```
SELECT s1.Name, s2.Name, l.Title
FROM Students s1, Students s2, visits v1, visits v2, Lectures l
WHERE   s1.Student_ID != s2.Student_ID 
    AND s1.Student_ID = v1.Student_ID 
    AND s2.Student_ID = v2.Student_ID 
    AND v1.lecture_ID = l.lecture_ID;
```

How do I eliminate combinations like this?
Note: This is not homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dedup this with `>` as follows

```
WHERE s1.Student_ID > s2.Student_ID
```

But you may want to use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) because it works when more than two students are in the same lecture.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(s.Name ORDER BY s.Name) Names, l.Title
  FROM Lectures l
  JOIN Visits v ON l.lecture_ID = v.lecture_ID
  JOIN Students s ON v.Student_ID = s.Student_ID
 GROUP BY l.Title
 ORDER BY l.Title
```

Comment: Thank you! I also added a `HAVING COUNT(s.Name) > 1` to get rid of lectures, which only have one student